# Как увеличить количество доступной виртуальной памяти для процесса на Linux x86?

Tags: linux

Я пытаюсь запустить программу (компилятор GCC), которая использует очень много оперативной памяти в процессе своей работы. Но к сожалению, она вылетает из-за недостатка памяти, когда её процессом было занято всего примерно 2,2 ГиБ виртуальной памяти (если верить системному монитору из Gnome). Я слышал, что на 32-ух разрядных ОС одному процессу может быть доступно до 4 ГиБ. Но в чём же причина такого расхождения, и можно ли как-то обойти это ограничение? Почему процесс не может забрать памяти по-максимуму?

Вот что я получаю в конце работы GCC.

```
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
```

А вот вывод команды `ulimit -a`.

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 16382
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Программу я запускаю в клетке chroot с 32-ух битным окружением на машине с 6 ГиБ ОЗУ. Это мне нужно, чтобы протестировать сборку для архитектуры i386.

Comment: А сколько физической памяти доступно и уже занято?

Comment: @0xdb, в момент прерывания компиляции занято примерно 3,3 ГиБ из 6 ГиБ. Плюс есть ещё 10 ГиБ для подкачки.

Answer (score 2):

В стандартном 32-битном ядре x86 smp каждый процесс может использовать 3 ГБ адресного пространства 4 ГБ и 1 ГБ используется ядром (разделяемое в адресном пространстве каждого процесса).

С 32-разрядным ядром x86 с 4G / 4G-разбиением «hugemem» каждый процесс может использовать (почти) всего 4 ГБ адресного пространства, а ядро ​​имеет отдельное 4 ГБ адресного пространства. Это ядро ​​было поддержано Red Hat в RHEL 3 и 4, но они сбросили его в RHEL 5, потому что патч не был принят в основное ядро, и большинство людей теперь используют 64-битные ядра.

С 64-разрядным ядром x86_64 32-разрядный процесс может использовать все 4 ГБ адресного пространства, за исключением пары страниц (8 КБ) в конце адресного пространства 4 ГБ, которыми управляет ядро. Ядро использует часть адресного пространства, которое выходит за пределы 4 ГБ, доступного для 32-битного кода, поэтому оно не уменьшает адресное пространство пользователя. 64-битный процесс может использовать гораздо больше адресного пространства (128 ТБ в RHEL 6).

Обратите внимание, что часть адресного пространства будет использоваться программным кодом, библиотеками и стеком, поэтому вы не сможете malloc () всего вашего адресного пространства. Размер этих вещей зависит от программы. Взгляните на `/ proc / <pid> / maps`, чтобы узнать, как адресное пространство используется в вашем процессе; сумма, которую вы можете malloc (), будет ограничена наибольшим неиспользуемым диапазоном адресов.

Comment: И вправду, есть довольно большой неиспользуемый кусок между 0x0b75d000 и 0x55598000 - https://paste.ubuntu.com/26201187/ Его как-то можно занять? Скажем, как-нибудь подвинуть все эти разделяемые библиотеки...